# How do I implement my Drawables most efficently

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

In my application i have a fragment with 4 images in jpeg(1000x350, about 130kb). I use these pictures between the header and the content of each Section.

Example:

```
///////// TEXT-HEADER ////// 
++++++ PICTURE ++++++++ 
------ Content-Text -------
```

Now i have a problem, when i am scrolling, it starts stuttering and i think a Galaxy S4 should have the power to display such things like images without a problem.

So my Question is:

How do I implement my pictures the most efficent way? Is there a chance of more perfomance, when i am using PNG or GIF?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html, the page will give you idea of how to handle large scale and display it on the screen.

Comment: File size, which stated, is not relevant.  This is just the size of the JPEG compressed data.  Unless you scale (see the link @Dara provided), those images each need about 1.3MB (height x width x 4 bytes).

Comment: One more thing: I reduced Imagesize again and the same thing happens. I already used AsyncTask to load images. I observed this a little bit and it seems like the last or first of the four images gets kicked out of cache, because thats the moment when the app lags for a while. If I scrolldown completly he stuckks at first image, when scrolling up and when i am scrolling down it stucks at the moment when image no 4 comes in. Is there a Way to keep android from kicking my drawables out of the cache?